cookies can only be modified in a server action or route handler next js
here is my singout action file code:


'use server'
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export const signout = async () => {
    cookies().delete("access_token");
    cookies().delete("refresh_token");
    cookies().delete("user");
    revalidatePath("/", "layout");
    redirect("/");
}



and here is my order action


"use server";
import axiosInstance from "@/components/axios";
import { signout } from "./signout_action";
import { returnCustomError } from "@/utilities/utils";

export const getOrders = async (pageNumber, query, filter) => {
    try {
        const res = await axiosInstance.get(
            `/api/reseller/orders/?page=${pageNumber}&search=${query}&status=${filter}`
        );
        return res?.data;
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.message === "Unauthorized") {
            signout();
        } else return [];
    }
};



now when user is unauthorized it run singout funtin and clear cookies in development mode and go to home page but ini the production it gives an error "cookies can only be modified in a server action or route handler next js" in the vercel logs
and show application error: a client side exceptions occured (see browser console)
this type of error shows on the screen
how to solve this in next js 14 app router

FYI: Your image has not been uploaded.

@TusharShahi which image

We can use Route Handlers for this purpose.
Let's add a new one in which we log out and delete all cookies.
/api/auth/logout/route.ts
import { cookies } from "next/headers"

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const body = await request.json()

    // change this part according to your need, just a simple fetch call for logging out
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_BASE_URL}/api/auth/logout`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${body.accessToken}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            accessToken: body.accessToken
        })
    })

    // this is the part you're looking for; deleting cookies
    const cookieStore = await cookies()
    cookieStore.getAll().map(cookie => {
        cookieStore.delete(cookie.name as any)
    })

    return Response.json({
        success: res.ok,
        status: res.status,
    })
}

Let's make a small change in your getOrders action and remove signout server action call
modified getOrders server action
"use server";
import axiosInstance from "@/components/axios";
import { returnCustomError } from "@/utilities/utils";

export const getOrders = async (pageNumber, query, filter) => {
    try {
        const res = await axiosInstance.get(
            `/api/reseller/orders/?page=${pageNumber}&search=${query}&status=${filter}`
        );
        return res?.data;
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.message === "Unauthorized") {
            // just return null if unauthorized
            return null;
        } else return [];
    }
};

and instead make an api call to logout in a client component
our client component
"use client"

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
import getOrders from "@/actions/getOrders"

const CC = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const fetchOrders = async (pageNumber, query, filter) => {
        const response = await getOrders(pageNumber, query, filter)

        if (!response) {
            // Unauthorized, logout
            const accessToken = session?.user?.accessToken || undefined
            // NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL is "http://localhost:3000" in dev mode
            fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/api/auth/logout`, {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify({ accessToken })
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
                .finally(async () => {
                    router.push("/")
                })
        } else {
            // orders fetched, keep going
        }
    }

    return (
        //...
    )
}

export default CC

